# PHP curl and string replacement

Tags: php, regex, curl, preg-replace

I had this code that I purchased many years ago that was working fine for me:

```
<?
$theLocation="http://www.ampolinc.com/wycieczki.php";
$baseURL="http://ampolinc.com/"; 

preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/)?([^\/]*)(.*)/i", "$theLocation", $matches);
$theDomain = "http://" . $matches[2];
$page = $matches[3];

$fd = fopen($theDomain.$page, "r");
$value = "";
while(!feof($fd)){
    $value .= fread($fd, 4096); 
}
fclose($fd);

// replace with your unique start point in the source of the HTML page
$start= strpos($value, "<td width=\"694\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">");  
// replace with the unique finish point in the source of the HTML page 
$finish= strpos($value, "<table width=\"709\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" style=\"margin:5px 0px 0px 167px;\"><tr><td>");  
$length= $finish-$start;

$value=substr($value, $start, $length);

$value = eregi_replace( "plan", "print", $value );   .
$value = eregi_replace( "fd9b1a", "ffffff", $value );

$FinalOutput = preg_replace("/(href=\"?)(\/[^\"\/]+)/", "\\1" . $theDomain . "\\2", $value);
echo "<base href=\"$baseURL\">"; // sets the remote site as the base, so that relative links are fixed.
echo "<font style=\"font-size: 9pt\">";
echo $FinalOutput; //prints it to your page
flush (); //force output faster
echo "</font>";

?>
```

but since the eregi_replace() was deprecated and removed in PHP 7, it doesn't work anymore

I am not a coder so when I was trying to make it work I only got to the point of displaying the content but I can;t replace the strings inside the page.

http://pentiger.com/download.php

to fix the links I need to replace words: 
 "plan" to "print"

This is the code I am now using

```
<?php
$baseURL="http://www.ampolinc.com/"; 
$curl = curl_init('http://www.ampolinc.com/wycieczki.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$page = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)) // check for execution errors
{
    echo 'Scraper error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    exit;
}

curl_close($curl);


$regex = '/<td width=\"694\" bgcolor=\"#FFFFFF\">(.*?)<table width=\"709\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" style=\"margin:5px 0px 0px 167px;\"><tr><td>/s';


if ( preg_match($regex, $page, $list) ) {    
    echo "<base href=\"$baseURL\">";
    echo "<font style=\"font-size: 9pt\">";
    echo $list[0]; //prints it to your page
    echo "</font>";       
} else 
    print "Not found"; 
?>
```

Ho can I replace strings within the $list before echo""?

Thanks

Comment: I just figured that this should work `$list= str_replace('plan','print',$list);`

Comment: @Barmar it is similar, but I didn't understand the answer to the question you mentioned.

Comment: You don't need a regular expression to replace `plan` with `print`, just use `str_replace`. `$value = str_replace('plan', 'print', $value)`

Comment: The final result of my endeavors is here: http://pentiger.com/wycieczki.php and original site is http://www.ampolinc.com/wycieczki.php

Comment: But if you did need to use a regexp, it would be `preg_replace('/plan/', 'print', $value)`

Comment: Where do you set `$list`? Is it a string or an array?

Comment: Not sure what you expect me to do with those urls. I can't see the PHP code.

Comment: @ barmar Those links are just to show that I finished it and it works the way it should. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were still having trouble becuse you didn't understand the duplicate question.